# list() function php does not work in PHP7 on Mac OSx

Tags: php, php-7

I was wondering how come the php function list() does not works on Max OSx but on Windows it does.

```
list($songAuthor, $songName, $songDate, $songSummary, $songPic, $songLyrics) = split(";", $data, 6);
```

I'm trying to parse a string `$data` into six different variables.

My PHP version is 7.0.8.

How can i make the code run in my Mac OSx?

Comment: In the future, please indicate what "does not works" means. Error messages? Unexpected function? etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not specific to Mac OSX, but to PHP7.

PHP7 removed [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) function - it had been deprecated for some time now.

> Warning This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP
>   7.0.0.

Try [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead which performs nearly same function (parsing string instead of regexp) and which generally leads to same results:

`list($songAuthor, $songName, $songDate, $songSummary, $songPic, $songLyrics) = explode(";", $data, 6);`